# Ajax Call ERror Cross Origin REquest: Pulling list of universities for autocomplete in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, autocomplete

I'm struggling to understand the concept of Ajax. My goal is simple, pull a list of educational institutions for an autocomplete form. Goal: user types something like "University of Wa" and then "University of Waterloo" might come up. Here's what my embedded ruby looks like:

```
<%= f.text_field :university, :id => "university-field", :onkeydown=>"updateUniSearch()" %>
```

And my javascript:

```
     function updateUniSearch() {
        /*jQuery UI Autocomplete for University Search Form*/
        $("#university-field").autocomplete({
             dataType: "json",
            source: "http://universities.hipolabs.com",
         async: true,
           crossdomain: true
        });
     };
```

I found a university names list API here: https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list

Currently, when I run my page, I get the following error:

```
    Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://universities.hipolabs.com/?term=university. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Am I on the way to doing this correctly, or am I way off? Again, I simply want to use the autocomplete to show a list of universities from an external source, rather than trying to find a massive list of universities and save them in a local array or something in javascript. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The dataType of `json` doesn't support cross-origin requests for security reasons. Try `jsonp` (JSON with padding) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not allow cross domain Ajax requests unless the [CSP (Content Sharing Policy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP) allows that domain or the source of the data provides [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) headers.

```
class ApplicationController

  before_action :set_csp, if: { request.format.html? }

  private
    def set_csp
      response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "connect-src http://universities.hipolabs.com 'self'"
    end
end
```

However the CSP and CORS are a relatively new innovations - back in the day the only way to do AJAX was by exploiting a hole in the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) which allows scripts to be loaded from any domain.

This uses is what is called JSONP - you take JSON and you wrap it in a javascript function. In order for it to work the API you are calling has to provide JSONP responses.

Unfortunatly `http://universities.hipolabs.com/search` does not provide JSONP responses.

You load the data by attaching a script tag to the DOM - when its done loading it calls the callback function which wraps the JSON. Sounds stupid? Yes it was. Fortunately you rarely need to use JSONP today as most worthwhile APIs send CORS headers and the CSP is pretty widely supported.

So you either need to just rely on the CSP or proxy the request through your own server.

```
require 'net/http'
class UniversitiesController < ApplicationController
  def search
    uri = URI("http://universities.hipolabs.com")
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params.permit(:name, :country))
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
      render json: res.body
    else
      head res.code.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Or just find a better data source that uses CORS to allow cross-domain access.